# MUI Stepper pass data to redux on next click

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, material-ui

So what im looking to do is a bit different. Below is a MUI Stepper:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { useTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import MobileStepper from '@mui/material/MobileStepper';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import KeyboardArrowLeft from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowLeft';
import KeyboardArrowRight from '@mui/icons-material/KeyboardArrowRight';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Unstable_Grid2';
import Step_1 from './step_1';
import Step_2 from './step_2';
import Step_3 from './step_3';
import Step_4 from './step_4';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { activeStepChange, showNextStepChange } from './Slice';


const steps = [
  {
    label: 'Selection 1',
    description:
    <Step_1 />
  },
  {
    label: 'Selection 2',
    description:
    <Step_2 />
  },
  {
    label: 'Selection 3',
    description:
    <Step_3 />
  },
  {
    label: 'Selection 4',
    description:
    <Step_4 />
  },
];

const Stepper = () => {

  const theme = useTheme();
  const maxSteps = steps.length;

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const activeStepRedux = useSelector((state) => state.Slice.activeStep);
  const nextStepRedux = useSelector((state) => state.Slice.showNextStep);

  const handleNext = () => {
    dispatch(activeStepChange(activeStepRedux + 1));
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    dispatch(activeStepChange(activeStepRedux - 1));
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{flexGrow: 1}}>
      <Paper square elevation={0} sx={{display: 'flex',alignItems: 'center',height: 50,pl: 2,bgcolor: 'grey',width:'100%'}}>
        <Typography>{steps[activeStepRedux].label}</Typography>
      </Paper>
      <Grid container sx={{ height: 675, width: '100%'}}>
        <Grid xs={12} alignContent={'center'} justifyItems={'center'}>
          <div>{steps[activeStepRedux].description}</div>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <MobileStepper
        variant="text"
        steps={maxSteps}
        position="static"
        activeStep={activeStepRedux}
        nextButton={
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleNext}>
            Next
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (<KeyboardArrowLeft />) : (<KeyboardArrowRight />)}
          </Button>
        }
        backButton={
          <Button size="small" onClick={handleBack} disabled={activeStepRedux === 0}>
            {theme.direction === 'rtl' ? (<KeyboardArrowRight />) : (<KeyboardArrowLeft />)}
            Back
          </Button>
        }
      />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Stepper;
```

SO the above code is very similar to what MUI has for a mobile stepper. However, under steps.description, i am importing components. Each of these components is a form.

What I want to do, is when the form is complete, and you press next on the stepper, dispatch that form data to redux.

What im not understanding is how to do that. For example, first form is 1 input field. When you enter data, it automatically pushes a name and the value to an object in local state. However, the stepper is the parent component, So i cant pass that local state up to it via props.

SO i need the next button, to pass that specific steps component data, to redux when clicked, and so on for each next step.

Is this even possible, or do i have to have all 4 steps inside the stepper?